# mousepad always blink in my debian10

Tags: debian

In Debian10, `leafpad` was removed and `mousepad` is the default editor.
I found an issue that my screen always blinks when I open `mousepad` in Debian10.

Comment: there are many things that "screen always blinks" might mean. could you be more specific?

Comment: also, Debian provides an easy way to report bugs for packages. just run `reportbug mousepad` and follow the instructions.